# Can't update text in Window with win32gui.DrawText

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to set up a non-scrolling text output window using Python in Windows.

I have found a few code examples that use win32gui.DrawText to place text in a window, but none of them add or change text after the initial text is in place.

I haven't seen anything in the documentation to indicate that the window text is fixed after DrawText is called, but I have been unable to make any changes after the window has been painted the first time.

What am I missing that will allow me to update the windows text?

Here is Christophe Keller's "Hello World" example that I modified to change the window text after 1 second.  (The code I added doesn't work.)

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import time

#Code example modified from:
#Christophe Keller
#Hello World in Python using Win32

# New code: Define global
g_str_Text = 'Hello send by Python via Win32!'

def main():
    #get instance handle
    hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle()

    # the class name
    className = 'SimpleWin32'

    # create and initialize window class
    wndClass                = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
    wndClass.style          = win32con.CS_HREDRAW | win32con.CS_VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc    = wndProc
    wndClass.hInstance      = hInstance
    wndClass.hIcon          = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
    wndClass.hCursor        = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
    wndClass.hbrBackground  = win32gui.GetStockObject(win32con.WHITE_BRUSH)
    wndClass.lpszClassName  = className

    # register window class
    wndClassAtom = None
    try:
        wndClassAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wndClass)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        raise e

    hWindow = win32gui.CreateWindow(
        wndClassAtom,                   #it seems message dispatching only works with the atom, not the class name
        'Python Win32 Window',
        win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        None)

    # Show & update the window
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hWindow, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(hWindow)

    # Dispatch messages
    win32gui.PumpMessages()

# New code: Attempt to change the text 1 second later
    time.sleep(1.0)
    g_str_Text = 'Something new'
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hWindow, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(hWindow)
    win32gui.PumpMessages()

def wndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):

    if message == win32con.WM_PAINT:
        hDC, paintStruct = win32gui.BeginPaint(hWnd)

        rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(hWnd)
        win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            g_str_Text,
            -1,
            rect,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

        win32gui.EndPaint(hWnd, paintStruct)
        return 0

    elif message == win32con.WM_DESTROY:
        print ('Being destroyed')
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0

    else:
        return win32gui.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 problems with your code:

1. [[ActiveState.Docs]: win32gui.PumpMessages](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32gui__PumpMessages_meth.html) is **blocking** til the window receives *WM_QUIT*, meaning that the code that follows it (that was supposed to redraw) will only be executed **after** you closed the window, and would also generate an exception, because at that time the *hWindow* handle will be invalid. Note that this problem also prevented the code running into the next ones
2. Neither of `win32gui.ShowWindow`, `win32gui.UpdateWindow` will trigger a window redraw because from what the window concerned, there was no change (no window area was *invalidated*). Typical user action that force invalidation is window resizing (including minimizing / maximizing). Note that moving the window, will also **not** redraw it
3. `g_str_Text = 'Something new'` - this doesn't do what you think it does, it's (a variant of ) a *Python gotcha*: it will create a new *g_str_Text* which will be **local** to *main*, instead of modifying the **global** one that *wndProc* uses to draw the window

To get past the problems, the code that redraws the window should be executed from a new *thread*. In order to do that:

- It was placed in a new function (*customDraw*)
- The thread starts **before** `win32gui.PumpMessages`, sleeps for one second and then changes the *windowText* value (note ***global***).
- It forces a window redraw via [[ActiveState.Docs]: win32gui.RedrawWindow](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32gui__RedrawWindow_meth.html) (which is a wrapper over [[MS.Docs]: RedrawWindow function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow)):

  - Signals the window that its client area that was invalidated (`win32con.RDW_INVALIDATE`)
  - Also it signals that the client area should be erased (`win32con.RDW_ERASE`), to avoid painting the new text over the old one
  - Sends a *WM_PAINT* message to the window

Here's your script with the above changes - note that I did some other small changes (e.g. renaming *g_str_Text* to *windowText*) to have only one naming convention - *camelCase* (which *BTW*, is **not** the *Python* recommended one):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import time
import threading

#Code example modified from:
#Christophe Keller
#Hello World in Python using Win32

# New code: Define global
windowText = 'Hello send by Python via Win32!'

def main():
    #get instance handle
    hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle()

    # the class name
    className = 'SimpleWin32'

    # create and initialize window class
    wndClass                = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
    wndClass.style          = win32con.CS_HREDRAW | win32con.CS_VREDRAW
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc    = wndProc
    wndClass.hInstance      = hInstance
    wndClass.hIcon          = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
    wndClass.hCursor        = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
    wndClass.hbrBackground  = win32gui.GetStockObject(win32con.WHITE_BRUSH)
    wndClass.lpszClassName  = className

    # register window class
    wndClassAtom = None
    try:
        wndClassAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wndClass)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        raise e

    hWindow = win32gui.CreateWindow(
        wndClassAtom,                   #it seems message dispatching only works with the atom, not the class name
        'Python Win32 Window',
        win32con.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        hInstance,
        None)

    # Show & update the window
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hWindow, win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(hWindow)

    # New code: Create and start the thread
    thr = threading.Thread(target=customDraw, args=(hWindow,))
    thr.setDaemon(False)
    thr.start()

    # Dispatch messages
    win32gui.PumpMessages()


# New code: Attempt to change the text 1 second later
def customDraw(hWindow):
    global windowText
    time.sleep(1.0)
    windowText = 'Something new'
    win32gui.RedrawWindow(hWindow, None, None, win32con.RDW_INVALIDATE | win32con.RDW_ERASE)


def wndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):

    if message == win32con.WM_PAINT:
        hDC, paintStruct = win32gui.BeginPaint(hWnd)

        rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(hWnd)
        win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            windowText,
            -1,
            rect,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

        win32gui.EndPaint(hWnd, paintStruct)
        return 0

    elif message == win32con.WM_DESTROY:
        print('Being destroyed')
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)
        return 0

    else:
        return win32gui.DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```